# Amen in Birchat Hachodesh

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, minhag, rosh-chodesh-new-month, amen

In the Birchat Hachodesh recited on the Shabbat before a Rosh Chodesh, in the final paragraph, there are a series of (what seem to be) requests for the upcoming month. I have seen in various congregations the practice of the congregation's saying "amen" after each of the items (eg l'tova v'livracha...). Though I haven't found a siddur or a list of minhagim that includes this, I have seen it at more than one synagogue.

But in the opening paragraph there is also a series of similar requests (titen lanu...chayim shel bracha etc.) but I have never heard anyone say "amen" after these items.

Why don't we say a similar "amen" after the items in the first paragraph?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to first ask why we say amen to each in the latter section? That seems significantly more unusual as prayers go.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought about that while I was writing but I remembered that there is also the same practice in musaf on Rosh Chodesh so I figured that doing it was precedented so I stuck with the question of why NOT do it in another case.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to first ask why we say amen to each in those two sections? That seems significantly more unusual as prayers go.

Comment: The Artscroll siddur (p. 648) discusses briefly the "amen" in musaf. Its logic doesn't exactly extend to birchat hachodesh, so the question of why "yes" in one section would be a distinct question to parallel why "no" in another section. If you have a good explanation for the why "yes" in BOTH cases, which would explain why "no" in the third, that would be appreciated!

Comment: In most Sephardic congregations I've been in, _amen_ is answered to the items on many lists, including e.g. קדשנו במצותיך ותן חלקנו בתורתך שבענו מטובך וכו׳.

Comment: Nitei Gavriel Rosh Hashana 29:23 says you can answer amen to a yehi ratzon even without mentioning Hashem's name. So, if anything, the first paragraph which has yehi ratzon we should say amen while in the second one when it didn't have yehi ratzon we shouldn't. Yet the minhag is just the opposite.